# Error when adding a column with ALTER TABLE on an existing table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, alter-table

We are getting this error when trying to execute an `ALTER TABLE` command on an existing table:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MStran_altertable, Line 1071
>   Invalid object name 'systranschemas'.

The alter table statement is:

```
alter table dbo.YARPF 
add YARSCWO char(3)
```

We have admin rights on the SQL server and database.

What can we do to track down and resolve this error?

Comment: Do you have replication enabled on that database?

Comment: yes we do, but when I searched for that error it didn't click in my head!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sp_MStran_altertable` procedure is called whenever an object is altered in a replicated database. You are getting the error because replication was partially removed.

You need to manually remove all references to replication. Technet has a good article on how to do this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152757(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks David, in fact we unchecked the relevant article in the replication properties then ran the statement before checking the article again.